# Most elegant way to ensure that is one process finishes another is terminated in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got two processes, if one finishes, the other should be killed. I'm fairly new to Python, so my first thought was to do this:

```
while(p1.is_alive() and p2.is_alive()):
    time.sleep(1)

p1.terminate()
p2.terminate()
```

But this seems pretty ugly, is there a better way?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Are `p1` and `p2` threads or subprocesses?

Comment: @SamChats Yeah, my bad.

Comment: They are `Process` objects. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: If the example syntax is accurate, forgive me the ugliness of comment formatting, then it almost becomes a `while True: if not p1.is_alive: p2.terminate() break; elif not p2.is_alive: p1.terminate() break; time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Linux or Windows? On Linux/unix you could catch the sigchld signal.